# How to trigger custom code when rendering is removed?

Tags: presentation, pipelines, events

I would like to trigger some code when a rendering is removed - actually gone, so not before the change is saved (you never know if an editor changes it's mind after removal and doesn't save).

I would need some information about the rendering, especially the datasource. Is there an efficient way to do this?  I was considering comparing layout fields on each save, but that might be a performance drain, no?

Comment: Comparing two strings on `item:saving` should be enough and not CPU heavy?

Comment: I need more than just a compare.. I need to find the renderings that disappeared and for each rendering the datasource. In both final and shared layout.. don't know what that would do on an item with a number of  languages and versions. It could be my only option though.

Comment: I assume you don't use workflow? If you do, then Final Layout field is workflowable... so technically, you don't want to remove the item UNTIL it has moved to approved state since at any point before the change could be rejected. You'll have to account for Shared vs Final Layout.

Answer (score 1):

A thorough dive into what happens when a rendering is removed has revealed that there's is not much triggered at all in Sitecore (Not like when a rendering is added which fires a pipeline). In fact, Experience Editor just removes the rendering and then relies on someone hitting the Save Button to actually save the changes, which at that point is merely just saving the field data.

#### item:saving Approach

I agree with Marek's comment in your question that hooking into the item:saving event should give you a look at what you're trying to discover. I do not think that you're going to find a solution that prevents you from having to compare the XML structs of the before and after item.

That being said, I found some code in the `saveUI` pipeline that looks to me, like it's attempting to do something similar to what you are trying to do.

#### saveUI Pipeline Approach

> BTW this is a total stab in the dark, but I'm going to try and provide
>   a thought.

When Sitecore save's an item, it executes the `<saveUI>` pipeline. As part of the arguments, it takes version and language into account.

In this pipeline, one of the processors is **ConvertLayoutField** which takes a look at the layout field before and after, and does some stuff. Here is the `Process()` method:

```
public void Process(SaveArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) args.Items, "args.Items");
  foreach (SaveArgs.SaveItem saveItem in args.Items)
  {
    Item obj = Client.ContentDatabase.Items[saveItem.ID, saveItem.Language, saveItem.Version];
    if (obj != null)
    {
      foreach (SaveArgs.SaveField field1 in saveItem.Fields)
      {
        Field field2 = obj.Fields[field1.ID];
        if (!field2.IsBlobField && !(field2.Type != "layout"))
        {
          string xml1 = field2.Value;
          string xml2 = field1.Value;
          if (!(xml1 == xml2) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml2)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml1) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml2)))
          {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument1 = XmlUtil.LoadXml(xml1);
            XmlDocument xmlDocument2 = XmlUtil.LoadXml(xml2);
            if (xmlDocument2 != null && xmlDocument1 != null && ConvertLayoutField.CompareNodes((XmlNode) xmlDocument2, (XmlNode) xmlDocument1))
              field1.Value = xml1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this processor, `SaveArgs` contain the **Item** being updated, and the fields that were updated.  In the processor above, is an example on identifying the layout field(s).

`xml1` is the field value before the save (coming from Item in the Content Database *field2*).
`xml2` is the field value after the save (coming from the SaveArgs Field *field1*).

So, a thought would be to create your own processor for this pipeline and use [`XmlDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa302294.aspx) to compare and get the differences on the layout field, and then do whatever work you need to do.